# Why is my array not empty in the onBeforeMount function but empty in the onMounted function

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-composition-api

thanks for your help.

In a component called "Student List", I am trying to fetch data from the API and instantiate that data into objects from the class Student and insert those objects into an array of Students called studentList in the onBeforeMount function.

Everything works great on the onBeforeMount function, The data is as expected fetched and inserted in the array studentList, however, when I check the array's data in the onMounted function, it shows that the array is empty with no data in it.

thank you for reading my post and for helping me out.

Here is the template section from the component StudentList.Vue
The child component shown changes depending on the studentList's size, if the studentList array is not empty, the child component TableList should be shown. Otherwise, the NodataFound child component should be shown.

```
<template>
  <section class="col-12" v-if="studentList.length !=0">
    <TableList :student-list="studentList" :page="pageNumber"/>
    <PaginationTable @pageNumberEmit="pageEmitReceived"/>
  </section>
  <section v-else>
    <NodataFound dede="test"/>
  </section>
</template>
```

Here is the script section from the component StudentList.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {inject, onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref} from "vue";
import TableList from "@/components/TableList.vue";
import {Student} from "@/types/Student";
import PaginationTable from "@/components/PaginationTable.vue";
import NodataFound from "@/components/NodataFound.vue";

const axios = inject('axios');
const pageNumber = ref(0);
const sizeNumber = ref(2);
const studentList: Array<Student> = new Array<Student>;


const props = defineProps({
  japanese: {type: String, required: true},
  english: {type: String, required: true},
  page: {type: Number, required: false},
})

function pageEmitReceived(page): void {
  pageNumber.value = page;
}

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(studentList.length);
})

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/' + props.english + '?page=' + pageNumber.value + '&size=' + sizeNumber.value);
    response.data.forEach(student => {
      let newStudent = new Student(student.uuid, student.name, student.email, student.dob);
      studentList.push(newStudent);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log(studentList.length)
})
</script>
```

when I check the array value with the vue webtool extension, I can clearly that the array is not empty.

[image: sstudentList variable values in it inspection]

Comment: It's possible that the api request completed after `onMounted` was run.

Comment: That's exactly the case. Using `await` in `onBeforeMounted` has no effect on when `onMounted` runs.  Hooks are just opportunities to run code at specific points in a component's lifecycle, but they do not themselves control the lifecycle, i.e. they don't rely on each other and therefore earlier hooks can't prevent or delay later hooks from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said, onMounted does not wait for beforeMount to finish before running.
Meaning your fetch is resolving after onMounted has already been called.

## Timeline:

--> Setup

--> beforeMount() called - fetch starts

--> onMounted() - runs with empty data

--> beforeMount() resolves - data is filled from fetch

To resolve this you could put the fetch at the top level in script setup, though this requires newer ES support as well as a Suspense parent around the component.

Or you could put the fetch inside the onMounted function.

Another issue is that your studentList array is not reactive, meaning when the data is fetched and pushed into student list, the display will not update to reflect this and NoDataFound will always show. Changing that line to:

```
const studentList = ref<Student[]>([])
```

and using `studentList.value` when pushing the data would fix this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. moving the function inside the onMounted() section and changing the array to a reactive type, solved my issue. thanks again.